# How to receive a GzString

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all

I'm trying to send a string via the Gazebo transport system. I managed to write a plugin that publishes the string I want as a GzString message. I now want to write a receiver that does something with the string. My starting point for this is [this listener example](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e18491b2ff1a9a99c2a8d6b3cd81584bbf2243b3/examples/stand_alone/listener/listener.cc?at=default).

The problem I have is that I don't know what to do with my received string in the call back function (called cb in the above example).
I have changed the call back function to accommodate for the fact that the message is a GzString as follows, but the change was essentially just a guess (replacing `ConstWorldStatisticsPtr` with `ConstWorldStatisticsPtr`) and I don't know if this is actually what I need to do. I can't find any documentation regarding this.

```
void cb(ConstWorldStatisticsPtr &_msg)
{
  // Dump the message contents to stdout.
  std::cout << _msg->DebugString();
}
```

The `->DebugString();` does not necessarily seem appropriate for a string, but I don't know what else to use or where to find documentation about this.

Can somebody help me or point me to where this is described?

Thanks,

Nick

P.S: What I'm trying to accomplish is to communicate joint angles back and forth. I would like to be able to have one message type that is able to handle a different number of joints.
Right now, I just write the joint names and angle values into the string and parse them out on the receiving side. I realize that this is not very elegant but I couldn't figure out a better way. If you can offer help in doing this differently, I would also be open to suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6992/how-to-receive-a-gzstring/) by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 186 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you want to use existing types to send info about a group of joints, you can use a model message, which can contain multiple joint messages. The joint messages have fields for name and also angles.

For an example of the message syntax, see [Model::FillMsg](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e18491b2ff1a9a99c2a8d6b3cd81584bbf2243b3/gazebo/physics/Model.cc?at=default#cl-794) and [Joint::FillMsg](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e18491b2ff1a9a99c2a8d6b3cd81584bbf2243b3/gazebo/physics/Joint.cc?at=default#cl-467).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on 2014-09-15**:
Thank you for your reply. Using Model::FillMsg, I can send a Model message. But I don't know how to get the data on the receiving end. I tried using Model::ProcessMsg(), but coudln't figure out how to create a Model object (the constructor wants a BasePtr _parent, which I don't have). I tried using the member functions that msgs::Model has, but it is not at all clear to me how to figure out what member functions there are. Is there any documentation for this? Thanks